# Angular Material 2: 'md-input' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

What am I missing here? Should `md-input` be individually loaded in the `module` file?

**This works:**

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput name="username" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" #name="ngModel" required>          
</md-input-container>
```

**However, this fails:**

```
<md-input placeholder="amount" align="end">
  <span md-prefix>$&nbsp;</span>
  <span md-suffix>.00</span>
</md-input>
```

with the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  </div>
  <div>
    [ERROR ->]<md-input placeholder="amount" align="end">
      <span md-prefix>$&nbsp;</span>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from "@angular/common";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { MaterialModule } from "@angular/material";

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import "hammerjs";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot() 
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in your second example the syntax is wrong. With the last 2.0.0 beta .1 (that I suppose you're using) the `md-input` keyword was replaced with `mdInput`. So if you desire an input styled with Angular Material 2 just type

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Username" name="username">
 </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your specifying your prefix and suffix incorrectly.  According to https://material.angular.io/components/component/input

> Prefix and Suffix
>
> HTML can be included before, and after the input tag, as prefix or
>   suffix. It will be underlined as per the Material specification, and
>   clicking it will focus the input.
>
> Adding the mdPrefix attribute to an element inside the
>   md-input-container will designate it as the prefix. Similarly, adding
>   mdSuffix will designate it as the suffix.

Instead of using `md-prefix` and `md-suffix`:

```
<md-input placeholder="amount" align="end">
  <span md-prefix>$&nbsp;</span>
  <span md-suffix>.00</span>
</md-input>
```

Try using `mdPrefix` and `mdSuffix` and wrapping it in an `md-input-container`:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="amount" align="end">
    <span mdPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
    <span mdSuffix>.00</span>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: tried that, same error: "Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-input' is not a known element:"

Comment: Sorry, I left off wrapping it in an md-input-contaner.  Check that.